# Drupal 6: Related "Locations" using Views

Tags: drupal, view, related-content

I have a custom field (field_locations ) which lists 20 different locations. I would like to use that field as an argument to obtain a block view that lists similar/related  locations.

Any idea on how to construct the argument?

Comment: You want to use the location field to list similar content in the block or you want to list locations similar to those in the content field? If #2, by what criteria I.e. is the location a simple taxonomy type or a node reference?

Answer (score 0):

Create a contextual filter for field_locations on your view.  Set the filter to provide a default value, using PHP code.  In the filter's PHP code, grab and return the value of your field or taxonomy term.